# Geocoding millions of addresses

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I have millions of addresses that I want to geocode and I can do that in ArcGIS but it would take me endless number of hours. Is there a faster method that you can recommend?

Answer (score 2):

I geocode millions of records all the time. The best method I have found, is to split the file into subsets so as to not run into 'out of memory' errors.

Also, right click your locator, and click properties. There is a 'performance' section, cranking up the 'Data cache size' speeds up geocoding immensely, same with 'Number of threads'. But make sure not too set it too high or memory issues ensue.

Comment: I am using the USA Geocoding Service and the only options that I see there are the matching sensitivity, intersections and output.

Comment: Ah, that's the ArcGIS Online service, not sure if you can mess with the performance properties of that. Might I suggest building a locator from Census TIGER data, or perhaps StreetMap premium.

Comment: I'm not sure the  performance section is in earlier versions of Arc. I think it came in at 10.1, at least based on a test I just did. There at 10.1, not there at 10.0, so if the OP isn't at that level, may not have performance section.

Edit: geocoding millions of records in AGOL will consume a very large amount of credits. A woman in a neighboring county used 40% of their annual credits in one pass, and I doubt she had millions of records.

Comment: Actually I have 10.2.2.

Comment: Yea its not possible to change performance settings for AGOL services, these performance features are enabled by building your own locator